# how to force Terminal to make reset after installing my cab?

Tags: c#, windows-ce, cab

how to force Terminal to make reset after installing my cab ?

i made C# program and cab for WinCE

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can include an [special dll file in your cab file named setup.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504675.aspx). Inside this dlls there are several functions you can implement:

- Install_Init
- Install_Exit
- Uninstall_Init
- Uninstall_Exit

During the [Install_Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee486157.aspx) function you could try to reset the device programmatically by calling

```
KernelIoControl(IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

However, as stated [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/11/25/windows-ce-resetting.aspx), the device OEM may or may not allow you to reset the device from a user application, so you may need to contact the OEM of the device for other alternatives.